# What is the equivalent to shift-drag in MS Paint for Gimp?

Tags: gimp, ms-paint

In MS Paint, if you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and drag a selection you will be able to "duplicate" your selection in "drag mode" (excuse my french).

My goal is to extend the edge of an image to create a wallpaper.

Comment: I don't think that exact feature exists in Gimp, there are other ways of doing what you're describing though. Why the photoshop tag?

Answer (score 2):

In Gimp, while in a selection tool, you can:

- Depress <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> to move (ie, Cut+Paste) the selection
- Depress <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> to copy (ie, Copy+Paste) the selection

Note that what you get is a "floating selection" so you still have to "anchor" the result (Ctrl-H) or make a new layer (Ctrl-Shift-N), so these moves are more like shortcuts for {cut|copy}+paste+move.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with MS Paint at all, but it sounds like you want to make a selection and duplicate it, and perhaps also increase the size of the canvas.

If so, you can resize the canvas using *Image > Canvas Size*, to make it as big as you require.

Then you can make a selection with one of the selection tools, use copy (CTRL+C), then paste (CTRL+V), move the floating selection with the Move tool (M) by clicking and dragging, or use the arrow keys for pixel precision.

When you have moved the selection into position, you can either Anchor the floating selection (CTRL+H), or promote the floating selection to a new layer (Shift+CTRL+N).